# Positive z score but lower mean value

Tags: r, glmm, z-score

I ran a GLMM to check the increase or decrease of the dependent variable on two fixed effects (condition "Presence and condition "Absence") as:

```
model <- glmer(Variable ~ Condition + (1|ID), weights = Session,  
               family=binomial, data)
```

It gave something like the following

```
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -9.914      1.195   -8.30   <2e-16 ***
Presence             0.755      0.274    2.76   0.0058 **
```

Looking at the positive z value, I would say that "Presence" increases in relation to "Absence" since.
However, the visualization of the conditions frequencies shows the opposite:

[image]

Does someone have an idea of what is happening here?

Comment: What exactly are you showing us in the graph? The results of the model suggest that presence has a stronger relation to the outcome, compared to absence.

Comment: The graph shows us the mean frequency per condition. I would expect to see an increase in the frequency of "Presence" that explains why that relation. Otherwise, with a visual representation like this, I would then expect a negative z-score. Or perhaps I got it all wrong, and I have been reading this in the wrong way....

Comment: You have weights as well, which may well complicate matters.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I controlled for overdispersion, by multiplying the standard error by the square root of the dispersion factor2 and recomputing the Z- and p-values accordingly